# How can i compute the mean of the gain

Tags: probability

I have 2 sets of data that I computed cdf for. I am asked to compute the gain. I can't seem to figure of how to conpute the mean to each set. I know mean is E[X] but I did have bunch of data x=[......] and y=[....] in matlab and I drew the cdf for each of those. Then how do I find the mean then. Should I find histogram first?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your data pertains to a non-negative random variable, I think you may calculate the
expectation as $E(X) = \sum_i (1-F(x_i))$ where $F(x)$ is the cdf. See here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305031/expectation-when-cumulative-distribution-function-is-given

More generally, you may have to calculate the probabilities $P(X=x_i)$ (using a histogram as you say) and use $\sum_i\,x_i \, P(X=x_i)$.